# Найти популярные слова в строке. Не могу найти ошибку в коде

Tags: javascript

Делаю на сайте check io следующую задачу.

Ваша задача в этой миссии определить популярность определенных слов в тексте.

На вход вашей функции передается 2 аргумента. Текст и массив слов, популярность которых необходимо определить.

При решении этой задачи обратите внимание на следующие моменты

Слова необходимо искать во всеx регистрах. Т.е. если необходимо найти слово "one", значит для него будут подходить слова "one", "One", "oNe", "ONE" и.т.д.
Искомые слова всегда указаны в нижнем регистре
Если слово не найдено ни разу, то его необходимо вернуть в словаре со значением 0 (ноль)

**Входные параметры:** Текст и массив искомых слов.

**Выходные параметры:** Словарь, в котором ключами являются искомые слова и значениями то, сколько раз они встречаются в исходном тексте.

**Пример:**

```
popularWords('When I was One \n\
I had just begun\n\
When I was Two\n\
I was nearly new', ['i', 'was', 'three', 'near']) == {
    'i': 4,
    'was': 3,
    'three': 0,
    'near': 0
}
```

**Предусловия:**
Исходный текст будет состоять из букв английского алфавита в верхнем и нижнем регистре, а также пробелов.

Решил ее так:

```js
var count = 0;
var obj = {}
var count = 0;

function popularWords(text, words) {
  var str = text.toLowerCase().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " ").split(" ");
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
      if (words[i] == str[j]) {
        count++;
        obj[words[i]] = count;
      } else {
        obj[words[i]] = count;
      }

    }
    count = 0;
  }

  return obj;
}

console.log('Example:')
console.log(popularWords(`
    When I was One
    I had just begun
    When I was Two
    I was nearly new`, ['i', 'was', 'three', 'near']))
```

Но не понимаю почему этот код не проходит проверку В консоли результат верен. Но checkio выдает ошибку

[image: error]

Странно то, что на скрине в "your result" попадают слова one и two, хотя я не передаю эти слова в качестве параметров в функцию.

Comment: плюс в ошибке указаны входные данные, твой результат и ожидаемый

Comment: и судя по всему ошибка показана не для текущего кода

Comment: задача решена правильно, но для текста без знаков препинания. на checkio не сообщается, какие тесты используются (вероятно там более сложные тесты с точками, запятыми и т.д.)

Comment: @АлексейОбухов, в ошибке пишется для каких входных данных был неверный результат. Знаков препинания там нет

Comment: обратил внимание, вы возвращаете глобальную переменную. код будет работать корректно, только если ваша функция вызывалась один раз. вероятно падает второй тест. внесите объявление obj внутрь функции. аналогичная проблема с count.